# Phonegap App , clicked pdf link will open in native pdf reader must disable share and print option

Tags: cordova, pdf, printing, sharing, reader

Inside my PhoneGap Application i have a external link which points towards a pdf. So it will open the pdf in the native pdf reader with the help of the [DocumentHandler-Plugin](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/documenthandler).

This plugins allows the user to print or share the pdf file. I don't want the user to share and print my pdf.

Please suggest me any another way to do comoplete this task, so that the user is not able to share or print my pdf file.